# How can I make a variable "refresh" itself every time my JavaScript file has code pulled from it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm working on a `Discord Bot`. I'm trying to allow the bot to send a message in response to a command containing one of the strings within a pre-defined array. In my case, the bot picks a random rap lyric from the array and says it.

**The problem:** The "randomizer" code that determines which string from the array is used, only runs once I activate the bot.
Here's the code:

```
var barnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * dababy_bar.length);

module.exports = {
    name: 'flamebar', 
    description: "spits out a flame bar",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send(dababy_bar[barnumber]);
    }
```

**I've already tried** sticking the `randomizer` at the end of the code, after module.exports, but that didn't have any changes in the results. I then tried to loop the "randomizer" forever, but that didn't work as the console froze whenever I started the bot up.

So how do I get my bot to run the `randomizer` on every call?

Comment: Why not just move the declaration and assignment for `barnumber` inside of your `execute` function?  Then it will be reinstantiated and assigned each time you call `execute`?

Comment: Hi chefanthonyy, and welcome to Stackoverflow. please edit your question and make it shorter and simpler and remove additional information that not need. take more chances to others to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the declaration and assignment of `barnumber` inside of your `execute` function, it will be set every time you call `execute`:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'flamebar', 
    description: "spits out a flame bar",
    execute(message, args){
        var barnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * dababy_bar.length);
        message.channel.send(dababy_bar[barnumber]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing your `barnumber` variable outside `module.exprts` will not work, because it will then only be **created** when you **start the bot** and will not change until you start it again.

To solve your problem you simply have to move the declaration & assignment to `execute`:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'flamebar', 
description: "spits out a flame bar",
execute(message, args){
    var barnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * dababy_bar.length);
    message.channel.send(dababy_bar[barnumber]);
}
```